# kdenlive Clip Opacity

Tags: video-editing, kdenlive

I'm new to kdenlive, and video editing, in general.  I'm trying to create a Title Clip with an opaque background and text foreground.  I wasn't able to figure out how to change the opacity of imported images, so I'm trying to create a second video track with the text-title-clip on one track as normal, and the image-title-clip on another track.  I was thinking I could just adjust the opacity of the image-title-track, but I'm not finding a way to do this.

It may also be the case that there are methods to accomplish this that I'm unaware of.  Any assistance would be appreciated.

Kdenlive 17.12.3

Linux Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

What I chose to do as a solution is use another editing option to create a static image with all the items I wanted in the Title Clip.  Then I just imported the image into the Title Clip.  Problem solved.